# Hi I need some help regarding some csv file and python data structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Hi I have three CSV file and I want to fetch data from all of the CSV and then instead of writing those CSV data I need to store in a dictionary of the list with the sheet name
Then from the 3rn CSV file, I need to overwrite data in the 1st and 2nd CSV file

```
csv1_data  //filename         csv2_data
marks1 marks2               marks3  marks4
  10     15                   11      12
   0     80                    4       5
  15     11                    4       3
  10     23                    2       0

csv3_data: //filename
marks1 marks4
  90     100
  87     80
```

so I need the output as csv1_data and csv2_data overwrite with values in csv3_data with available values like that

```
  csv1_data                   csv2_data
  marks1   marks2             marks3 marks4
    90       15                 11     100
    87       80                  4      80
    90       11                  4     100
    87       23                  2      80
```

and the final output I needed like this:

```
 output = [('csv1_data',[{'marks1':90,'mark2':15},{'marks1':87,'mark2':80},{'marks1':90,'mark2':11}, 
 {'marks1':87,'mark2':23}]),('csv2_data',[{'marks3':11,'marka4':100},{'marks3':4,marks4:80}, 
 {'marks3':4,'marks4':100},{'marks3':2,'marks3':80}])]
```

Comment: Show your code pls.

Comment: @CC7052 yes I will update with my code

Comment: Start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Just dumping your homework assignment here isn't helpful. Start with it. If you hit a problem, isolate that problem and do research on that. If nothing helps, consider asking here. Don't ask here before even starting.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Hi I tried but I didn't get the correct output, that way I am asking

Comment: show what you tried so we can further assist you

Comment: and how does your data look in a csv file, attach a photo

Comment: Read input files, combine the data, write output files. The first step is to read just a single input file. Do that first. Search the web for "how to read a CSV file in Python" to get an idea. If that poses problems you can't solve, as a question here.

Comment: @coderoftheday of I will share with you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('f1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('f2.csv')
df3 = pd.read_csv('f3.csv')
df = pd.concat((df1,df2), axis=1)
df[df3.columns] = df3
```

df is a pandas.DataFrame object that holds all your data from df1 and df2 overwritten by df3.